# Layout and Drawable issues in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

I am often getting confused with the image sizes and button sizes that I am using for the android app.

I know that the buttons and images must be placed in folders such as `drawable`, `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi` but i am not clear the about the sizes to be mentioned in those folders that used for the app.

Please help me in explaining this. For example, if I am using a background image for my app, then what must be the size of the image in default and in each folder what sizes to be placed.

In case of the layout I know that I have to use folders such as `layout`, `layout-large`, `layout-small`, `layout-xlarge`. For example in this folder I am having the following xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_screen"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

For the `android:background` image for each layout, from which folder is the image fetched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will give you a better understanding...

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: i have gone through this document.... what size of image to be placed in drawable folder? either the maximum size or the minimum size??

Comment: that's what you have to decide according to your app and use nine png image format...http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html